# useState passed to useContext not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use useContext to create a generic Tooltip component that passes a close() function to the content inside the Tooltip. I have written my Tooltip like this

```
export function Tooltip(props) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    const close = () => {
        setActive(false);
    }

    return (
            <div className="tooltip-wrapper"
                onClick={() => setActive(true)}
            >
                {props.children}
                <TooltipContext.Provider value={{close}}>
                {active && (
                    <div className='tooltip-tip bottom' ref={node}>
                        {props.content}
                    </div>
                )}
                </TooltipContext.Provider>
            </div>
    )
}
```

I create the Tooltip in a different class component as follows

```
function Category(props) {
     return (
            <Tooltip content={<AddCategoryInnerTooltip name={props.name}/>}>
                  <p className="tooltip-name-opener">{props.name}</p>
            </Tooltip>
     );
}

function AddCategoryInnerTooltip(props) {
    const {close} = useContext(TooltipContext);

    return(
        <div className="inner-tooltip-wrapper">
            <input
                className="tooltip-custom-input"
                type="text"
                defaultValue={props.name}
            />
            <div className="button-end">
                <button onClick={close}>Cancel</button>
                <button>Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I attempt to call `close` within the `AddCategoryInnerTooltip`, the state passed from the `Tooltip` component doesn't update. When I `console.log` the state, it always comes as `true` without changing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

should be a callback function

```
<button onClick={()=>close}>Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I tried this. Writing the button like this as a callback function also does not change the state